# how to get index from father element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML following

```
<div id="father">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I want to get to the children's index.
In JQuery,there's something to get index
At the first,we click the first div and get the index 0

```
$(".child").click(function(alert($(this).index())};
```

But when the HTML is:

```
<div id="father">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <p>some text</p>
      <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

When we click the forth div and get the index 3 not 2
I try to use or someelse method,but to no avail.

```
$(".child").index(":not(p)");
```

Is there something simple method can meet the requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: Just add it to your selector `$(".child:not(p)")` but anyway, there's no point doing this if `p` does'nt have the `child` class

Comment: have you actually read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/) on how to use this function? Because your question makes no sense given how the function actually works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,and sorry for my question unclear.
At the first,we click the first div and get the index 0
and when we add the p as the above,
we click the forth div and get the index 3 not 2,
I want to ask how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count previous siblings which also have class "child":

```js
$('.child').click(function() {
    var count = $(this).prevAll('.child').length;
    console.log(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="father">
      <div class="child">AAA</div>
      <div class="child">BBB</div>
      <p>CCC</p>
      <div class="child">DDD</div>
</div>
```

For reference, check: https://api.jquery.com/prevall/

Comment: I read the official menu.
It's the magic method I do not know.
And Thanks to you two commentor complement my questions as you can.

Comment: Try clicking the last div, isn't it the answer you need? `$.prevAll()` is just another method from jQuery like `$.index()`

Comment: Dear @Washinhton： Yes.I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.index()` to find the location of the `<div>` clicked relative to it's parent. Filtering the selection to only `#father > div`.

```js
$("#father > div").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="father">
      <div class="child">Foo</div>
      <div class="child">Bar</div>
      <p>some text</p>
      <div class="child">FooBar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply.I;m sorry for myquestion imcompletely.
I edited it.